# Spring security context, several users

Tags: spring, spring-security

I don't understand one thing. If for example 5 users are logging into your application so spring security creates 5 different context ? I'm little confused about contexts in spring.

All components in spring are Singleton (by default). So if I create one component and two different authenticated users are working on this component so they are working on the same data ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SecurityContext` is kept in `SecurityContextHolder` with thread local strategy by default. Which means that `SecurityContext` will be scoped to a thread.

In Spring MVC application each request runs in its own thread. And Spring Security (`SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` in particular) populates the `SecurityContextHolder` with `SecurityContext` found in the HTTP Session (if one already exist).

So if five users are logged in your application, five security contexts will exist but only the one belonging to the user making the request will be available from the thread handling the request.

And for the second part of your question, yes, multiple users will be working with the same instances of your singleton scoped beans. But I'm not sure that is a problem. Your singleton beans may be services, DAOs, etc. and you probably don't store a state on those which can be directly changed by the users.

Hopefully this brief and simplified post explained it, if not leave a comment and I'll add more details.

**More information:**

- [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.html)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for answer. You explained very well and now i understand it ! If I have session scope and user logout so security context of this user is removed form security holder? Btw what kind of scope is Model in MVC.

Comment: When you logout Spring Security will destroy the SecurityContext and invalidate the HTTP session associated with it. And as for the Model scope. Not sure I understand this. Model is not a scope in terms of MVC. It is something used to present data to a view.

Comment: So if 5 users are in contextholder so there are usinng the same model ?

Comment: No. The model you pass to view from controller is request scoped and as I explained for each request there is one SecurityContext belonging to the user making the request in the SecurityContextHolder.

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Here is an example when there is a problem coming from that. I would like to figure out exactly how, and what to do with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011895/spring-security-context-returns-another-user