# Spring security context returns another user

Tags: java, servlets, spring-security

I have made a servlet filter to do custom authentication (based on a header set by the apache fronting my tomcat). If there is already an authentication object in the security context, I am using this.
However in some cases that authentication object belongs to another user, not the one making the request.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there a way to reliably get the authenticated user, or should I always do the authentication in the filter?
If I have to do the authentication every time, is it okay to create a new Authentication object (which is a wrapper around my user entity), or it would lead to memory leak, so I should cache those objects?

Here are the relevant parts of the code:

```
@Service
public class RemoteAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean
    implements Filter {

  @Override
  public void doFilter(
      final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res,
      final FilterChain filterChain
  ) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    final SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    if (
      context.getAuthentication() == null ||
          !context.getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()
    ) {
       //creating an Authentication in auth
       SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    } else {
      // in this branch context.getAuthentication() sometimes returns another user
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(req, res);

  }

}
```

Comment: I note that you fail to _clear_ the context once you're done processing. One more reason not to invent your own authentication mechanisms.

Comment: Where and how I should have done that? After the doFilter call by setting Authentication to an unauthenticated one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you never clear `SecurityContext` and since it uses `ThreadLocal` to store authentication, if the same thread is used to process the next request, it still retains the previous authentication.

I would suggest you to add `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()` after `chain.doFilter(req, resp)`, get rid of `if-else` statement and just create a new authentication for each request.